# How to send/pass the string on Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm getting into trouble with passing paramters by URL in Zend Framework. I want to access the update page by a URL like this: http://example.com/mycontroller/show/aabbcc

and i used `$paramName = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');` 
for get the parameter. But it still doesn't work. And here's the error message below.

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

No Exception available
```

if i access like this http://example.com/mycontroller/show/1 it's working. But i want to send a string to my page. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you share your routing configuration please? Also, where you call the line `$paramName = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch() ...`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a constraint in your route for that parameter.

You have to remove that constraint or update it to allow integers and strings.

Comment: ya. I sett  'id' => '[0-9]*', and i replace with this 'id'=> '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', it's work. Thx for your solution.